# standard function to replace a charecter in a C array with multiple charecters?

Tags: string, arrays

I have a char array with some special characters in it. I have to replace this special character in the array with another predefined multiple characters.

Let's say the special characters and corresponding values  are something like below:

< --->  &#34 ,
@ --->  &#35

Currently I am comparing each character within the input array for special character, and replacing the same with predefined value in output array as shown in code snippet below:

```
 char istr[100] = "This is < a input string @ 123";
    char ostr[100];
    char * p = istr;
    int ic = 0;
    int oc = 0;
    while(*p)
    {
         if(*p == '<')
         {
             ic++;
             ostr[oc++] = '&';
             ostr[oc++] = '#';
             ostr[oc++] = '3';
             ostr[oc++] = '4';
         }
         if(*p == '@')
         {
             ic++;
             ostr[oc++] = '&';
             ostr[oc++] = '#';
             ostr[oc++] = '3';
             ostr[oc++] = '5';
         }

         else
         {
             ostr[oc++] = istr[ic++];
         }

        p++;
    }
    ostr[oc++] = '\0';
    printf("%s",ostr);
```

Is there any better way or standard function in c which I can use for replacing a single char with multiple chars?

Comment: You need to resize the array.

Comment: Doing this your way doesnt add the multiple characters to the string, but replaces the existing values in the string

Comment: Either make ostr 4 times greater than istr (if your case is limited to replacing 1 char with at most 4 chars) or use malloc+relloc.